# Creating 1000 unique samples from a dataset without replacement

Tags: r

I am not really familiar with programming in R and my problem is the following: I have a dataset of 55 observations. I want to create 1000 new samples of length 45 out of this dataset that have to be unique (no two samples can be the same). What I tried is this, but it does not give me the wanted result:

```
set.seed(830219)

Newsample <- numeric(1000)  

for(samp in 1:1000){ 
New <- sample(Xij, 45, replace=F)
sam[boots] <- unique(New)
}
```

Any hints or solutions? Many thanks!

Comment: What are `Xij` and `boots`?

Comment: This is really a duplicate of your previous question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137375. Because it is purely an `R` coding question, I vote to migrate it to [SO].  It might help you to know that in your application you do *not* need all these samples to be unique and that it is unlikely that many of them would be duplicated even if you were to sample with replacement rather than without replacement.

Comment: you don't need to put in a loop, instead you can write `replicate(10000, (sample(Xij, 45, replace =F)))`

Answer (score 0):

If `Xij` is the name of your dataset (vector), you can use this command:

```
Newsample <- replicate(1000, sample(Xij, 45))
```

This will create a matrix with 1000 columns and 45 rows.

Comment: I am not sure whether this solves the problem. Your solution basically means that no value occurs twice in the original data. However, I think it is still possible that two samples are identical (= not unique)

Comment: @MarkusRehm Thanks for pointing out. I suppose I misunderstood the question.